# Difference between assigning array directly and through function

Tags: c, pointers

Say I have an existing array `int *array`

```
int *new_array = NULL;
new_array = array;
```

```
int *copy(int *array)
{
return array;
}

int* new_array = NULL;
new_array = copy(array);
```

What's the difference between the two?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: no difference except a function call, the result is exactly the same. Notice that you copied nothing, after operation both `array` and `new_array` points to the same address, meaning, the same data.

Comment: The two code snippets do the same thing, and in particular, neither one makes a copy of the array.

Comment: look at [`memcpy`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html) if you want to actually copy the data from `array` to `new_array`.

Comment: Does the actual code you are having a problem with look more like `int *foo(void) { int array[something]; return array; }` than `int *copy(int *array) { return array; }`?

Answer (score 1):

Arrays cannot be assigned in C language. In your examples, you assign a pointer with reference to the first element of the array.
Your second snippet also only assigns pointer with pointer returned by the function. It does not copy data referenced by those pointers.

> Say I have an existing array int *array

It is not an array - it is a pointer to `int`

If you want to copy elements of one array to another array you need to use function `memcpy` or `memmove`

```
int array1[5] = {1,2,3,4,5}
int array2[5];

memcpy(array2, array1, sizeof(array1));
```